# Rails6 Search function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ive been trying to implement a simple search function but even though i kinda got it going I'm having trouble rendering the view. i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s88Uc0InOAM
and i was getting an error "AdsController#search is missing a template for request formats: text/Html" i think i fixed that by adding a render "index" at my function in the controller but i don't know if it ok to do so? So first i would like someone more experienced to review the code? And secondly, how am i supposed to style the results? as it is the page renders with the search result on the left side and in a simple card i have using bootstrap, but i would like for it to be in the middle of the screen for instance/or trigger the show path of the post upon clicking search.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :ads
  root 'ads#index'
  get 'search', to: "ads#search"
  
end
```

ads controller

```
def search
    @ads = Ad.where("title LIKE ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%")
    render 'index'
  end
```

this is my navigation partial

```
<div class="container mt-2 mb-5" >
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-5" ><%= link_to 'Αντάλλαξε!', new_ad_path %></button>
            <form class="form" action="/search">
              <input class="form-control" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Αναζητησε!" aria-label="Search">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-5" > Search </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the tutorial said to have another search.html.erb file and just render the ads directly

```
<%= render @ads %>
```

but that doesnt work so i rendered the index file inside the search function. So once again is this ok ?is it correct? do i have to create another template if i want to restyle the search result?

Comment: if you add a search.html.erb inside the ads folder of view in that case you don't have to mention anything, by default it will render search.html.erb . I am not sure what do you want here? I guess, you want to show the search result here in that case it's better to render new file instead of index. Though it will totally depend on what do you want. You can add search.html.erb under ads folder in view . that's it.

Comment: as i mentioned below i do have a search file which as per the tutorial it should render the @ad but this way it doesnt work. and thank you for the reply! i just want to understand it properly

Comment: you don't have to render ad or ads. By default rails search for `app/views/your_controller/your_action.html.erb` if you explicitly mention to render another file then it will render that file else it will render the your_action.html.erb. In your case you don't have to mention anything just create a file search.html.erb under app/views/ads folder. and remove the render 'index' from your action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a template for the `search` action.

Rails tries to render a template for all `get` html requests.

You need to add a file named `search.html.erb` to `app/views/ads/`, it will represent your search results.

But I'll recommend you to use [Ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) to make things easier

Comment: thank you for replying.i do have a search.html.erb file but as the tutorial said inside it I have a <%= render @ad %> which then shows this error. ActionView::MissingTemplate in Ads#search. if I remove the render index in the search function it doesn't display anything. I'm new to rails so i thought it might be the way my posts are handled but mostly i wanna try and understand why it doesn't work the same way the tutorial showed